# ListView with Thumbnails not scrolling smooth

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with thumbnails. And I am getting the thumbnails from an url. I am showing a spinner when the thumbnails are being downloaded.

**Problem**
On the start of the listview, when all the spinners are replaced by the downloaded images at almost the same time. The spinners freeze, and the listview kind of freezes for 0.5 seconds.

When I'm scrolling through my listview with a noticeable speed, the same happens.

**Question**
How can I speed up my listview, and make it smooth again? Should I perform some tasks on the background, or download and set the images one-by-one. Or maybe something else?

**GetView**

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
    }

    UrlImageView thumb = (UrlImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    final Video video = videos.get(position);
    // Set the image for the list item
    thumb.setImageDrawable(video.getThumbUrl());    
    return convertView;
}
```

I also notice, that if i use **if(convertView == null){** to recycle list items, sometimes the wrong thumbnail is shown.

**UrlImageView**

```
package com.package;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

import imports;

public class UrlImageView extends LinearLayout {

private Context mContext;
private Drawable mDrawable;
private ProgressBar mSpinner;
private ImageView mImage;

public UrlImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public UrlImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

private void init(final Context context) {
    mContext = context;

    int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    mImage = new ImageView(mContext);
    mImage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width,height));
    mImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mSpinner = new ProgressBar(mContext);
    mSpinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    mSpinner.setIndeterminate(true);

    addView(mSpinner);
    addView(mImage);
}

/**
 * Set's the view's drawable, this uses the internet to retrieve the image
 * don't forget to add the correct permissions to your manifest
 * 
 * @param imageUrl the url of the image you wish to load
 */
public void setImageDrawable (final String imageUrl) {
    mDrawable = null;
    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mDrawable = getDrawableFromUrl(imageUrl);
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(RESULT_OK);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(RESULT_CANCELED);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                imageLoadedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(RESULT_CANCELED);
            }
        };
    }.start();
}

/**
 * Callback that is received once the image has been downloaded
 */
private final Handler imageLoadedHandler = new Handler(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case RESULT_OK:
            mImage.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
            mImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case RESULT_CANCELED:
        default:
            // possible fail image
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});

private static Drawable getDrawableFromUrl (final String url) throws IOException, MalformedURLException {

    return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(url).getContent()), "name");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this official blog post for some tips:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: Thank you, I noticed the post before, though I have some difficulties applying it to my app. It would be amazing if you could help me get started!

Comment: Can you specify what exactly was difficult? You can start with the ViewHolder, it's relatively simple. It actually looks like your image loading is already performed in the background.

Comment: I have implemented the viewholder, I don't notice any difference though. - And I'm wondering why my listview is not running smooth if I am performing all image-related tasks in the background. I'm also using the latest hardware (Nexus 5) and the source of the "unsmoothless" should really be in UrlImageView.java

Comment: Maybe you can try to add caching to your images. There are also ready made libraries that can help you with image loading in Android. e.g. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader